# How to login into Gitkraken using organisation git hub

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I have a pro git kraken account.I am exploring Glo boards to synchronize to my organization github but it always redirects to https://github.com .I have added my organization account into github enterprise with personal access token in the preferences option.
How to login into my organization's git account?

Answer (score 0):

Try to push or pull, you will be prompted for your github credentials, one you put them in should be linked.